# How Token_loader works in flask-login?

Tags: python, flask-login

I have a simple app where the first page after login is decorated with @login_required.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from flask import render_template,request, redirect, url_for, flash, abort,Blueprint
from flask_login import login_required,login_user, logout_user,LoginManager
from app.models.User import Users
from app import app
from app.config import config
import datetime

admin = Blueprint('admin',__name__)

loginManager = LoginManager()
loginManager.init_app(app)
loginManager.login_view = 'admin.login'

user = None

app.REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION = datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)


"""@loginManager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
     return user"""

@loginManager.token_loader
def load_token(token):
     print "In Token Loader"
     return user


@admin.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        if username == config.username and password == config.password:
            global user
            user = Users('100',username,password)
            login_user(user,remember=True)
            print "redirecting url"
            return redirect(url_for('admin.index'))
        else:
            flash('Incorrect Credentials')
            return redirect(url_for('admin.login'))

@admin.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
     logout_user()
     return redirect(url_for('admin.login'))

@admin.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
     return render_template('index.html')
```

As you can notice the @user_loader callback is commented out,

when @user_loader not commented, 
1. The login is validated successfully
2. First Page is shown successfully (index method in code)
3.@Toke_loader callback is not called

I wanted @token_loader callback to be called so I commented @user_loader

When @owner_loder is commented
1. Login is validated (I can see the token is generated)
2. But failing in loading index method and the stack trace is as below

```
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 46, in <lambda>
    current_user = LocalProxy(lambda: _get_user())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 794, in _get_user
    current_app.login_manager._load_user()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 363, in _load_user
    return self.reload_user()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 325, in reload_user
    user = self.user_callback(user_id)
```

What I deduced is, since I commented @user_loader call back it is set to None and hence I am getting the error

The reason why I tried to comment @user_loader is because i assumed if i comment @user_loder callback then @token_loader callback will be called but looks like @user_loader is mandatory.

How can I make @token_loader to be called?